# Compiler does not recognize OpenCV library

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual studio 2013 and opencv 3.0.0. 
I would like to run this code:

```
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <opencv\highgui.h>

using namespace cv;

int main(){

    //Generate matrix to store image
    Mat image;

    //initialize capture
    VideoCapture cap;
    cap.open(0);

    //Create window to show image
    namedWindow("window", 1);

    while (1){
        //copy webcam stream to image
        cap >> image;

        //print image to screen
        imshow("window", image);

        //delay 33ms
        waitKey(33);

    }

}
```

However, I got the following errors:

```
first.cpp(12): error C2065: 'VideoCapture' : undeclared identifier
1>first.cpp(12): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'cap'
1>first.cpp(12): error C2065: 'cap' : undeclared identifier
1>first.cpp(13): error C2065: 'cap' : undeclared identifier
1>first.cpp(13): error C2228: left of '.open' must have class/struct/union
1>          type is 'unknown-type'
1>first.cpp(16): error C3861: 'namedWindow': identifier not found
1>first.cpp(20): error C2065: 'cap' : undeclared identifier
1>first.cpp(23): error C3861: 'imshow': identifier not found
1>first.cpp(26): error C3861: 'waitKey': identifier not found
1>
1>Build FAILED.
```

I linked the library conveniently. The compiler receives the opencv library. However, it gives such errors.

Comment: please do not use the deprecated c-headers, like opencv/cv.h and opencv/highgui.h but `#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>`

Comment: Ok. You are right.Those errors are gone. Now, I am getting this error: `1>ClCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'opencv_world300d.libopencv_ts300d.lib'
1>
1>Build FAILED.` @berak

Comment: are you lacking a 'space' to separate those 2 library names ? 'opencv_world300d.lib opencv_ts300d.lib' , not 'opencv_world300d.libopencv_ts300d.lib'